# Search with Wildcard PHP

Tags: search, wildcard

I have a search form to search for usernames. And I have maked SQL Wildcard LIKE but it only print one username?? I have also tried to while it, but it doesn't?

```
$besked = "&nbsp;";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['username'])){

            $username = $_POST['username']; 
            $getHeads = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE '%".$username."%'") or die(mysql_error());


            while($headInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($getHeads))
            $besked = "<a href='member.php?id=".$headInfo['id']."'><font color='blue'><h3>".$headInfo['username']."</h3></font></a>";

                } else
            $besked = "No user found!";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it's hard to find what's causing the problem. However, there are a lot of errors in the code you provided, so try fixing those first.

### Problems

1. Why are you wrapping everything in two `if` statements? Just use `&&` to check both variables in the same `if`.
2. You're mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions. Don't do that, `mysqli` and `mysql` are two different database abstraction layers, and should not be used concurrently in your application.
3. It's possible that I'm misinterpreting your script so I will leave this part untouched in the edited code below, but your `if` statement is checking that both variables are set, and if they are not, you're telling the user "No user found!". However, what this should probably say is, "Please enter a search term," because you're not actually searching for any users.
4. Try to write more organized code. You're missing some curly braces, and it's probably causing the script to brake.
5. Not a backend problem, but I just feel the need to remind you not to use the `<font>` tag. Use CSS instead.

---

```
$besked = "&nbsp;";
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $getHeads = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE '%".$username."%'") or die(mysqli_error());
    while($headInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($getHeads)) {
        $besked = "<a href='member.php?id=".$headInfo['id']."'><font color='blue'><h3>".$headInfo['username']."</h3></font></a>";
    }
} else {
        $besked = "No user found!";
    }
// Echo out the result
echo $besked;
```